# process text in html and reinsert to html structure

Tags: php, html

i want to grab text from HTML do some process and change to it and reinsert to that HTML code with php.

```
<p>This is my    sentence   <span>and   more</span> also <strong>important</strong> part.</p>
```

What's the best method? Using preg_* ? how can i reinsert my text to HTML style ?

for example i want to remove all double or more spaces between words.

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $myText);
```

but i want just applied in text of my html not html tags, attributes or etc ...

Comment: Update noted: Is the example moot, since the extra spaces in your example will collapse down into a single space anyway? In any case I would have thought the `preg_replace` example you provided would work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at DomDocument. It'll allow you to do some manipulation on your HTML.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

**EDIT**

If you want to elaborate on exactly what you want to do with your HTML example, we might be able to provide a more specific answer :)

**EDIT**

To reflect the updated answer: the multiple spaces in HTML should collapse anyway, but if you want to remove them then you could try the following:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=\>)[\w\s]+(?=\<)/', function($match) {
    return preg_filter('/\s+/', ' ', $match[0]);
}, $str);
```

I'm not a regex expert by any stretch so I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this, but this might work for you nonetheless: first do a `preg_replace_callback` and use lookarounds to grab any text fragments between end and start tags. Then, pass the result through `preg_filter` (or `preg_replace`) to replace any multiple spaces as a single space.

Hope this helps/works :)